# Extract the first part of of file name up to a pattern in Bash

Tags: bash, match, extract, filenames, parameter-expansion

This seems to be a common sort of problem, but I haven't seen an answer that works in Bash directly. What I've got so far, using the case where I want to grab the file name up to the first blank or period, where $f is the filename (e.g., f="filename-fileversion filetype.file-subtype"), is

```
echo ${f#*[. ]}
```

which does what I want, but it leaves me with the remainder of the string (filetype.file-subtype) when what I want is the excluded part (filename-fileversion) and

```
echo ${f%[. ]*}
```

which gives me the first part of the string, but it matches to the last occurrence of the pattern (filename-fileversion filetype). Variations moving the asterisk before/after the pattern end up returning the entire filename.

Is there a way to do what I want without resorting to an external program?

Comment: You may try: `"${f%%[ .]*}"`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Details in the manual: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)